# Trying to code a Chess Notation Translator with Lex and Yacc

Tags: parsing, yacc

I am trying to write code to translate the chess notation into a normal language.The input to your program will be a text file containing the moves of a chess game written in the well-known chess notation.

Examples are shown below;

1.f2-f4 e7-e5

2.f4xe5 d7-d6

These are the notations and the translation of those notations are shown below;

f4xe5 -> White pawn on f4 takes the piece on e5.

d7-d6 -> Black pawn on d7 moves to d6.

Bf8xd6 -> Black bishop on f8 takes the piece on d6.

The problem occurs when I try to execute the program with an example input. The program prints nothing to the output txt. It gives error at line 1. And here's my input file;

1. e2-e4 e7-e5
2. Ng1-f3 Ng8-f6
3. Nf3xe5 d7-d6
4. Ne5-f3 Nf6xe4
5. d2-d4 d6-d5
6. Bf1-d3 Nb8-c6
7. O-O Bc8-g4

And the ouput file should look like this;

move 1

The white pawn on e2 moves to e4.

The black pawn on e7 moves to e5.

move 2

The white knight on g1 moves to f3.

The black knight on g8 moves to f6.

move 3

The white knight on f3 takes the pawn on e5.

The black pawn on d7 moves to d6.

move 4

The white knight on e5 moves to f3.

The black knight on f6 takes the pawn on e4.

move 5

The white pawn on d2 moves to d4.

The black pawn on d6 moves to d5.

move 6

The white bishop on f1 moves to d3.

The black knight on b8 moves to c6.

move 7

The white is castling to King’s side

The black bishop on c8 moves to g4.

lex file:

```
        digit   [0-9]
       
        letter  [A-Za-z]
        %{
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include "y.tab.h"
        int linenum=1;
        %}
        %%
        "K" return King;
        "Q" return Queen;
        "R" return Rook;
        "B" return Bishop;
        "N" return Knight;
        "x" return captures;
        "-" return moves;
        "+" return check;
        "#" return checkmate;
        "." return POINT;
        " " return WHITE;
        {letter}({letter}|{digit})* {yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return IDENT;}
        [0-9]+  {yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return INTEGER;}    
        [ \t]+
        ("#".*) 
        . 
        %%
```

yacc file:

```
        %{
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include "y.tab.h"
        void yyerror(char*);
        int yylex(void);
        extern FILE *yyin;
        extern int linenum;
        char writeBuffer[300];
        FILE *outputFile;
        void openFile(char*);
        void writeLinetoFile(char*);
        void closeFile();
        %}
        %union
        {
        char *string;
        }
        %token <string> INTEGER  
        %token <string> IDENT
        %type <string> variable_value
        %type <string> normal_move
        %type <string> chess_chars
        %type <string> chess_moves
        %token King,Queen,Rook,Bishop,Knight,captures,moves,check,checkmate,POINT,WHITE;
        %%

        program:
            program statements
            | 
            statements
            ;

        statements:
            normal_move
            ;

        variable_value:
            INTEGER
            {
                sprintf($$,"%s",$1);
            }   
            |
            IDENT
            {
                 sprintf($$,"%s",$1);
            }
            ;

        chess_chars:
            King
            {
                 sprintf($$,"K");
            }
            |
            Queen
            {
                  sprintf($$,"Q");
            }
            |
            Bishop
            {
                   sprintf($$,"B");
            }
            |
            Knight
            {
                   sprintf($$,"N");
            }
            ;

        chess_moves:
            captures
            {
                  sprintf($$,"x");
            }
            |
            moves
            {
                  sprintf($$,"-");
            }
            |
            check
            {
                  sprintf($$,"+");
            }
            |
            checkmate
            {
                   sprintf($$,"#");
            }
            ;

        normal_move:
             INTEGER POINT WHITE IDENT chess_moves IDENT WHITE IDENT chess_moves IDENT
             {
                   sprintf($$,"move %s\n",$1);
                   sprintf($$,"The white pawn on %s %s to %s", $4,$5,$6);
                   writeLinetoFile(writeBuffer);
             }
             |
             IDENT chess_moves
             {
                    sprintf($$,"The white pawn on %s%s to ", $1,$2);
                    writeLinetoFile(writeBuffer);
             }
             ;

             %%
             void openFile(char *fileName){
               outputFile=fopen(fileName,"w");
             }
             void writeLinetoFile(char *str){
               fprintf(outputFile,"%s",str);
             }
             void closeFile(){
               fclose(outputFile);
             }
             void yyerror(char *s){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error at line:%d\n",linenum);
             }
             int yywrap(){
                return 1;
             }

             int main(int argc,char *argv[])
             {
                openFile("output.sh");
                yyin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
                yyparse();
                fclose(yyin);
                closeFile();
                return 0;           
            }
```

Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Were you required to use lex and yacc?

Comment: What is the purpose of `{letter}({letter}|{digit})* {yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return IDENT;}`? That rule makes it impossible for King (and the tokens for the other pieces) to be recognised.

Comment: I used {letter}({letter}|{digit})* {yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return IDENT;} to identify string notation and yes lex, yacc are required for this.

Comment: What is "string notation", concretely, and what does it have to do with identifiers? What part of `Nf3xe5`, for example, are you trying to capture? As written, it matches the entire move, which cannot be correct.